# How to detect that the page was just restored from the page cache (eg. From the Back button) in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a situation that when a user came back to a page by clicking back button then I need to send an ajax request.
Is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: I found a solution.      $(function(evt){
   if (evt.persisted) {
    
   } else {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
     url: '<?php echo base_url("Cart/defalut_cart_menu")?>',
     success:function(data){
      $('#cart-menu-1,#cart-menu-2').html(data);
     }
    });
   }
  })    This check returns false if a page is loaded or loaded from  cache or by clicking back button.

Answer (score 1):

The following article should answer your question:

[Detecting when a page is loaded from the browser cache.](http://monket.net/blog/articles/detecting-when-a-page-is-loaded-from-the-browser-cache/)

The concept of the above article is that at every request you set the cookie from the server side and check the cookie using JavaScript (or jQuery). if the cookie matches that of the previously requested page, then it is a cached page. If it doesn't, it is a fresh page.

Hope that helps.